# Error al solicitar pdf con ajax, XmlHttpRequest

Tags: jquery, ajax, pdf, blob, xmlhttprequest

Tengo una funcion que hace una peticion a un endpoint de una API, esta api arma un pdf y responde, el problema es que aparece un mensaje de error en la peticion ajax:

Este es el error que obtengo como respuesta.

> Uncaught DOMException: XMLHttpRequest.responseText getter: responseText is only available if responseType is '' or 'text'.

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
function ImprimirApiExterno(url, elemento = null) {

ShowModalCargando(true);

$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    processData: false,
    xhrFields: {
        responseType: "blob"
    },
    success: function (response, status, xhr) {
        console.log("Operacion exitosa")
        try {
            //ShowModalCargando(false);
            let blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            let URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            let downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            if (elemento === null)
                window.open(downloadUrl);
            else {
                let iFrame = document.getElementById(elemento);
                iFrame.src = downloadUrl;
            }

        } catch (ex) {
            ShowModalCargando(false);
            console.log(ex);
        }
    },
    error: function (err) {
        ShowModalCargando(false);
        console.log("Error al intentar realizar la impresion: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

}

- Ya intente omitir el `responseType`, y me entrega un pdf vacio
- Intente usar una version de `JQuery` mas actual y no funciono (uso la
  1.11.3)
- Intente omitir el `contentType`, no funciono
- Al parece ni siquiera pasa por el success
- Ya probe el mozilla, en google chrome y el error persiste
- Probando en postman, si funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente pude realizar de otra forma, la hipotesis principal es la version de `JQuery` que se esta usando en el proyecto (un poco antigua)
El codigo quedo de la siguient forma

```js
                                                                         
      try {
         //Tuve que usar XMLHttpRequest en lugar de $.ajax
         var req = new XMLHttpRequest
         //Url del endpoint, metodo get 
         req.open('GET', url, true)
         req.responseType = 'blob'
         req.onload = function (res) {
             console.log(req.response)
             let blob = new Blob([req.response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
             let URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
             //Abrir el document en una nueva pestana
             let downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
             window.open(downloadUrl);
         }
         req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
         //Agregar el token
         req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', sToken);
         //Enviar peticion
         req.send()
     } catch (err) {
         ShowModalCargando(false);
         console.log("Ocurrio un error al solicitar la impresion")
         console.error(err)
     }
```

Por si a alguien mas le sirve.